# Perl random string, but doesn't seem so random when used in a browser

Tags: perl, random

This is driving me nuts! I have a script that needs to create a random id, so that the file can be renamed. Here is a test I have:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    my $test = rand_id();
    print "FOO: $test\n";
}

sub rand_id {
# Used for the file names (not temp_id, for new adds)
  use String::Random qw(random_regex random_string);
  my $rand = random_regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]"x20);
  return $rand;
}
```

This works as I hoped:

```
root@admin:# perl test.cgi
FOO: P2kyuotdlk04gcafvoze
FOO: ZGC44tXfGFaiXeHsLZdn
FOO: fydWFp1PW6iGYFaOfgvx
FOO: xG4SPx2gLGPVeMJOupZ9
FOO: 6A2uD9hCF90VP7ybKjiA
FOO: wT4fG8ogmV37Mkljs0gE
FOO: 6QttcmlNjO1o9jCVht3g
FOO: 9bAYYDd2NIjBWgAhsl3t
FOO: hrU04kHvxu0JJYPHv6Jk
FOO: 9EVL9GqGdWWZhDam6dc9
FOO: F0zruszqvmMOUumlO4Q1
FOO: KA9jOof9iSTxpDOWUMBl
FOO: phicMiogMhZIcPZiXvj8
etc
```

So all good (no repeats).

I then have almost the same code (just not in a loop) in my script, but when I keep reloading from the browser I get:

```
NEW: 0ab3K60sJSpHrvDVCKcR
NEW: 0ab3K60sJSpHrvDVCKcR
NEW: 0ab3K60sJSpHrvDVCKcR
NEW: 0ab3K60sJSpHrvDVCKcR
NEW: 0ab3K60sJSpHrvDVCKcR
NEW: EyiYp5D6d8CL3vzozYFZ
NEW: EyiYp5D6d8CL3vzozYFZ
NEW: EyiYp5D6d8CL3vzozYFZ
NEW: EyiYp5D6d8CL3vzozYFZ
NEW: EyiYp5D6d8CL3vzozYFZ
NEW: A0KUBiNSDcxyX7JQzBsk
NEW: A0KUBiNSDcxyX7JQzBsk
NEW: A0KUBiNSDcxyX7JQzBsk
NEW: A0KUBiNSDcxyX7JQzBsk
NEW: A0KUBiNSDcxyX7JQzBsk
NEW: 7wU3RgK1Ho16rEjkGSsB
NEW: 7wU3RgK1Ho16rEjkGSsB
NEW: 7wU3RgK1Ho16rEjkGSsB
```

As you can see, there are LOTS of duplicated "random" ids. What am I doing wrong?

The module I'm using is http://search.cpan.org/~steve/String-Random-0.20/Random.pm , but I'm getting the same problem when doing stuff with even something like:

```
my $rand = Digest::MD5::md5_base64( rand );
```

Comment: How are you testing your server? Maybe a cache is interfering? The `rand()` function is not a good source of randomness. Depending on how your program is called, it may use a completely unsuitable seed (see `srand()`), e.g. if your server forks a process per request. You may want to use a module that guarantees a specific PRNG algorithm or entropy source. If you want to generate unique identifiers, use an appropriate module (in a pinch, something based on PID + time + per-process sequence number is a good approximation).

Comment: @amon thanks. The first test script was run from ssh, using a `for` loop (as you can see). The 2nd example was done by printing the string to STDERR, and then tailing the log file. I then reloaded the same script multiple times, to see what was happening.

Comment: @amon - thanks, that got me on the right track :) I ended up using `Crypt::PRNG::random_bytes_hex(15)` to get what I want. Its now perfectly random :) Please add that as an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: As @Amon says below, if you're making tempfiles, then use File::Temp.  It takes care of this issue as well as many others.

Comment: @AndyLester thanks - its not a temp file though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why you might get unsuitable IDs:

- The server or browser may be caching a response (unlikely in this case, but always worth investigating).
- The random number generator was initialized in a server process that then forks a worker process for each request. The worker processes then inherit the RNG state. For plain CGI, this is unlikely because a new process is forked and execed for each request.
- The random number generator was initialized with a weak seed, e.g. `srand(time)`. Since time() has a 1-second resolution, you'll get the same seed for all processes started within a second. It is not recommended to manually initialize `srand()` unless you want to get repeatable “random” number sequences.
- The built-in `random()` function may use a low-quality algorithm. It is absolutely not suitable for cryptographic purposes. Use a module that guarantees a particular PRNG and is seeded with a proper entropy source.
- Random numbers may occur multiple times. For true randomness you can calculate the collision probabilities with the Birthday Paradox. Unless the collision probability is astronomically small, your application needs to be able to avoid duplicate IDs.

If you're just trying to generate unique IDs without any security properties, use an existing generation algorithm (e.g. UUIDs).

In a pinch, you can easily generate such IDs based on PID + current time + a per-process sequence number:

- The PID is unique per machine for a some time, typically hours (though possibly less when the machine is rebooted or has a low pid_max).
- PID + time with at least second resolution should be a unique process identifier over the existence of a machine (ignoring time zone shenanigans).
- To avoid assigning the same ID if multiple IDs are requested within a second, add a per-process counter.

Note that such IDs are predictable, and shouldn't be used to designate security-sensitive data. Applying a hash function does not add any protection, but conveniently boxes the ID into a fixed width. These IDs are unsuitable when they must be unique across multiple machines.

If you're just trying to generate tempfiles, use an existing module such as [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp).

Comment: Using an existing module won't necessarily help for the most likely cause of the problem (bullet #2) (since they might simply use `rand` themselves), and you missed the simplest solution for that cause: Call `srand();` (without arguments) in the child after `fork`.